# Why is this IntStream.mapToObj mapper not evaluated with Stream.count?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I use an `InStream.range` with a `mapToObj` mapper as a substitute for-loop to initialize a database for a test by creating some records, which then I want to count to verify that the correct number has been created.

I have noticed that the `Stream.count` terminal operation returns the correct count, but when I use the `count` method from my persistence layer it returns `0`. The mapper callback is not being called and thus no records are created.

Here is a sample that demonstrates the issue:

```
public class IntStreamTest {

    private final List<String> db = new ArrayList<>();

    @Test
    public void mapToStringAndCount() {
        long count = IntStream
            .range(1000, 1010)
            .mapToObj(this::mapToString)
            // .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .count();
        Assert.assertEquals(10L, count);
        Assert.assertEquals(count, countString());
    }

    private long countString() {
        return db.size();
    }

    private String mapToString(int i) {
        String string = String.format("string-%d", i);
        System.out.printf("%s%n", string);
        db.add(string);
        return string;
    }
}
```

When I use the intermediate operation `Stream.filter` after `IntStream.mapToObj` everything works fine. Also the the records are created when is use `Stream.collect` after `IntStream.mapToObj` or IntStream.forEach`instead of`IntStream.mapToObj`.

Why does `IntStream` behaves like this?

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu219.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu219.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: The test terminates without errors with jdk8. Can you add the failing test?

Comment: @Giovanni this behaviour is specific to Java 9+. You've tested with Java 8. See the linked duplicate. The moral is: don't rely on mappers to give you side effects; for side effects, use forEach.